# How to read from STDIN in python from a piped grep output

Tags: python, linux, bash, grep

Let's say I have a text file and `grep "@" file.txt` returns:

```
(1) preparing corpus @ Tue Apr 28 20:19:31 CEST 2015
(1.0) selecting factors @ Tue Apr 28 20:19:31 CEST 2015
(1.2) creating vcb file /media/2tb/ccexp/phrase-mkcls-mgiza-10clusters/work.en-ru/training/corpus/en.vcb @ Tue Apr 28 20:19:31 CEST 2015
```

And I want to use my python script that reads that output using something like:

```
grep "@" file.txt | python process.py
```

I've tried this (`process.py` but it only reads the first line:

```
import sys
logfile = raw_input()
print raw_input()
```

[out]:

```
(1) preparing corpus @ Tue Apr 28 20:19:31 CEST 2015
```

**How do I read all the lines piped into the python script?**

Comment: `for line in sys.stdin:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @AshwiniChaudhary suggested:

```
import sys
log = "".join([i for i in sys.stdin])
print log
```